# Is there any vim plugin that could restrict spell check only in comment in c source code file?

Tags: vim

I'd like to turn on spell check to avoid typos in comment, but in code those red underlines are really annoying...

Some file type plugins could do that for other languages, like Python, but I couldn't find any c plugins.

I tried [c.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=213) but it doesn't work.

Comment: Vim's included filetype plugins should already do this. I'm using version 7.3 here and with no special configuration when I `:set spell` in a `.c` file it only does spell checking in comments and strings.

Comment: I assume he wants to avoid having spelling errors highlighted in his strings.  That's what I tried to answer in answer I gave. . .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to modify the c syntax file to get the behavior you want.  When you load a c file (or set a file to c filetype) the c syntax file is loaded from the /vimxx/syntax directory, it's the file there named c.vim.  This file has all the various syntax statements that establish elements that can be highlighted.

You will notice several statements throughout the file that end with `contains=` and have `@Spell` among the groups that are "contained".  If you remove `@Spell` from these statements (mostly string syntax items) and leave `@Spell` in the contains clause for "comment" elements (e.g., `cComment`) that should do what you want.

Be careful not to remove `@Spell` from any `contains=ALLBUT,` clauses, which, as you might guess, list syntax items that may *not* be contained in the given group.

Comment: I happened to have used a very old c syntax file.  Oh, I've been using vim for 10 years already!